# Remove a array from an multidimensional array using object value in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

i need to remove duplicate array from below array.

first and third arrays are same, consider only "id"

```
$data = [
          [
              'id' => 'test_fun%test',
              'text' => 'test_fun',
              'data-value' => 'test',
          ],
          [
              'id' => 'test_fun1%test',
              'text' => 'test_fun1',
              'data-value' => 'test',
          ],
          [
              'id' => 'test_fun%test',
              'text' => 'test_fun',
              'data-value' => 'test',
              'selected' => true
          ]
    ];
```

i'm tried to below code.

```
-> array_unique($data);

-> array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $data)));
```

Expected Output

```
  $data = [
          
          [
              'id' => 'test_fun1%test',
              'text' => 'test_fun1',
              'data-value' => 'test',
          ],
          [
              'id' => 'test_fun%test',
              'text' => 'test_fun',
              'data-value' => 'test',
              'selected' => true
          ]
    ];
```

Comment: Somebody wanting to answer this question needs to use an awful lot of their precious time. 

- What do exactly mean by "using object value"? It is guesswork to try to see what you mean.
- Instead of some weird array dump, could you please give initialization to get your array. This way the people answering have something working to build on.
- What the hack are  `$all_lambda` and `$all`?
- What exactly did you try to do with your "below code"?

Please when writing a question, please formulate it with consideration how it can serve the future generations of Stackoverflow users, too.

Comment: Your criteria isn't clear. Is the second element kept because it has `'selected' => true`? Can this duplication be avoided at the source (the place where this array is built in the first place)? What does serialization have to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

`array_unique` is not going to work since you have `"selected"` in the third array. I agree with the comments that this is quite unclear but to me it seems you're looking for a custom filtration rule, so a plain old `foreach` is the tool for the job.

```php
<?php

$data = [
    [
        'id' => 'test_fun%test',
        'text' => 'test_fun',
        'data-value' => 'test',
    ],
    [
        'id' => 'test_fun1%test',
        'text' => 'test_fun1',
        'data-value' => 'test',
    ],
    [
        'id' => 'test_fun%test',
        'text' => 'test_fun',
        'data-value' => 'test',
        'selected' => true
    ]
];

$filtered = [];
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $selected = $row['selected'] ?? false;

    if (isset($filtered[$id])) {
        if (!$selected) {
            continue;
        }
        unset($filtered[$id]);
    }

    $filtered[$id] = $row;
}

// optional use if you don't want ids for keys
$filtered = array_values($filtered);


print_r($filtered);
```